# Tensorflow returns same predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to make my first tensorflow model, however I have some issues. It seems that it makes the train correctly, but when it does a prediction it just returns (almost) always the same value. Here's the code:

```
n_classes = 2

tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder('float')
y = tf.placeholder('float')
keep_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,1,32]),
           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,32,64])),
           'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([54080,1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
           'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


def conv3d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv3d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool3d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool3d(x, ksize=[1,2,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

def convolutional_neural_network(x, keep_rate):
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, IMG_SIZE_PX, IMG_SIZE_PX, SLICE_COUNT, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool3d(conv1)


    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool3d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1, 54080])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out'])+biases['out']

    return output

much_data = np.load('F:/Kaggle/Data Science Bowl 2017/Script/muchdata-50-50-20.npy')

train_data = much_data[:-100]
validation_data = much_data[-100:]


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x, keep_rate)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for data in train_data:
                X = data[0]
                Y = data[1]
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: X, y: Y, keep_rate: 0.75})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

            print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:[i[0] for i in validation_data], y:[i[1] for i in validation_data], keep_rate: 1.}))

        print('Done. Finishing accuracy:')
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:[i[0] for i in validation_data], y:[i[1] for i in validation_data], keep_rate: 1.}))

        eval_data = np.load('F:/Kaggle/Data Science Bowl 2017/Script/eval_data-50-50-20.npy')

        probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
        sol = []
        for data in eval_data:
            X = data[0]
            id = data[1]
            probs = probabilities.eval(feed_dict={x: X, keep_rate: 1.})
            pred = prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: X, keep_rate: 1.})
            print('Outputs: ',pred)
            print('Probs: ',probs)
            sol.append([id, probs[0,1]])
        print(sol)
```

I have also checked the predictions during the training of the model and, if I set keep_rate to 1, I also get almost always constant predictions towards the end. In the first epochs there is a lot of variation, but in the last epochs it seems the neural net is always predicting the same for every image. It seems it converges to a unique prediction value, without taking into account what image I pass to the neural net. I checked hundred times but can't see where the mistake is.

This is an example of what I get for some images in eval_data (same behaviour when I print for train_data):

```
Probs:  [[ 0.76099759  0.23900245]]
Outputs:  [[-0.017277  -1.1754334]]
Probs:  [[ 0.76099759  0.23900245]]
Outputs:  [[-0.017277  -1.1754334]]
Probs:  [[ 0.76099759  0.23900245]]
Outputs:  [[ 117714.1953125   -47536.32421875]]
Probs:  [[ 1.  0.]]
Outputs:  [[-0.017277  -1.1754334]]
Probs:  [[ 0.76099759  0.23900245]]
Outputs:  [[-0.017277  -1.1754334]]
Probs:  [[ 0.76099759  0.23900245]]
Outputs:  [[-0.017277  -1.1754334]]
Probs:  [[ 0.76099759  0.23900245]]
```

Notice that they are almost always the same, but from time to time I see some bizarre value like

```
Outputs:  [[ 117714.1953125   -47536.32421875]]
Probs:  [[ 1.  0.]]
```

Hope somebody has the answer, this is giving me headaches.

Thanks a lot for your patience! I'm still a newbie in Tensorflow :D

Comment: When I get this result it usually means that the network isn't learning anything at all. It's getting a set of outputs, and optimizing the result as best it can as if there was no input at all. This probably means something is horrifically wrong (e.g. bug). Start debugging with the input to the model (data and labels). Output/visualize exactly what you're feeding to the model and prove to yourself that you're actually giving the model what you believe you're giving it, tons of bugs occur at this point. Simplify your model until you can get some kind of result, then start adding things back in.

Comment: Another common mistake that produces this result is to send the model the same batch of data over and over again. That should pop up if you dump a few batches of data and actually visualize them. The issue here is probably trivial, finding it is often not so trivial.

Comment: Thank you David for your insights. I have just double checked whether I was feeding with same data over and over but it's not the case, all the inputs are different and they "make sense", as I have visualized them also. My fear is that I'm not feeding the network correctly in some step. I assume that for every step in the for loop it takes one element of train_data, passes it through the net and updates the weights, and it makes it in the end 10 times (10 epochs) per item.

Comment: Also I don't understand why there are sometimes those "weird" outputs that are not the same. So 90% are all equal values but around 10% are these strange values, which anyway don't make any sense.

Comment: Is your dataset balanced?

Comment: Did you actually output these values: `X = data[0]` and `Y = data[1]`? I usually write a function that will take those raw values and visualize them. I've seen data input errors quite a lot of times, and have found it worth asking twice. Also, during training you should at least be outputting your loss, are you seeing it go down? If not, perhaps the network is just diverging and you need to tune something, lower learning rate perhaps? I usually start with 1e-4 or 1e-5. Let us know what the output of the loss function is during training.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro, how do I check my dataset is balanced?

Comment: @David Parks. Yes, I have output the actual predictions in the whole training process. At first these values are very different and huge and towards the end of the training the start converging to a unique value (it's never the same because of the dropout, but when I set it to 1 then it's the same)

Comment: Loss is actually going down. At first, because I update the net at every image, if the prediction is correct the cost is usually 0 and if the prediction is incorrect the cost is usually huge. This happens because in the beginning predictions for 0 and 1 are so different that they make cost go to 0 or infinity. Towards the end this cost starts getting more "sensible" values. I calculate epoch cost as the sum of the cost for every update, which does indeed decrease over time. I haven't really tried with lower learning rates than 0.001, might give it a try but don't think it's the issue.

Comment: @giust Its the distribution of positive and negative labels, ideally it should be 1:1, but if its very unbalanced, like 99% positive and 1% negative, it can be the cause of this problem.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro the distribution is 72% one class 28% the other, so it's not ideal but not crazy either

Comment: @giust Note how the odd probabilities are 76% and 24%, quite close to the class distribution. This makes me conclude that the unbalance is the issue.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro I don't see how the conclusion arises. If I had 50% and 50% I would probably still have constant outputs around 50% and 50%, so the issue would still be there.

Comment: @giust that's a hypothesis, and I don't think it is true. What happens is that the class unbalance makes it easier to for the network to just learn to output one class, as it will get 76% accuracy by just doing that. Balance your dataset and see how the outputs change.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro has a good point, and it's an easy problem to solve, just oversample the underrepresented class until they're roughly equal. Neural networks will cheat whenever possible.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro Thanks for the hint, I'll let you know something as soon as I try! Is this a normal issue when training neural nets, so I should always make sure it's (almost) ideally balanced?

Comment: @David Parks Not good news, after balancing my datasets I get the same kind of behaviour.

Comment: Ok, so cost is coming down, you're not diverging it sounds like, balanced data set. The next most common issue is that your labels don't match your data, perhaps they're not permuted the same somehow? Something isn't matching up here. Simplify things until you get something basic working then build it back up. Also, how are you creating your 3D image, in that dataset you have a variable number of 2D slices I see, I assume you're concatenating them together?

Comment: @David Parks I checked and labels match the images. For building the dataset first I resize the images (they come too big to be processed) and they consist of 20 slices of 2D images. I visualized them and they do make sense. The whole process is here: https://www.kaggle.com/sentdex/data-science-bowl-2017/first-pass-through-data-w-3d-convnet
I even copied and pasted everything, and tried to build it in 3 different ways, and getting same results. I tried to ask there but nobody is replying. The only part that is not there is the prediction, so maybe there's something wrong in my eval_data loop?

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem and it took me two weeks to find the reason. It might help you. My problem is due to the noisy dataset and high learning rate. Since ReLU activation could kill the neuron, when the dataset is noisy, most of the ReLUs will dead (not activate to any input, because it considers its input as useless), then the network might only learn some fixed distribution of final labels. So the results are fixed to any input.

My solution is using `tf.nn.leaky_relu()`, because it will not kill the Negative inputs.